# How To Use Forward Declaration In C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, forward-declaration

I have 2 classes Main-Server and Sub-Server ,The main-server class has a sub-server vector as a memmber.in addition I want that the sub server will inherited methods (void run()) from the main-server class, but I got the error "forward declaration of 'struct cMain_server " .
Could you help me please what I am doing wrong? Forward declaration doesn't work for me..

hpp:

```cpp
class cMain_server;
class cSub_server : public cMain_server {
 public:
  // Constructor
  cSub_server();

 private:
};
class cMain_server {
 public:
  // Constructor
  cMain_server();
  void run();

 private:
  vector<cSub_server> mSub_server_vec;
};
```

Comment: I think you should switch the order. Declare the sub-server in the first line, then define the main server and finally define the sub server.

Comment: @SomethingSomething Unfortunately that won't help, unless the vector is changes to something like `std::vector<cstd::unique_ptr<Sub_server>> mSub_server_vec;`

Comment: You can make this work through use of pointers and a lot of sweat, blood & tears, but it seems like just bad design.

Comment: @Elior As already mentioned, I also believe, that this is a serious design flaw: A _SubServer_ cannot be a _MainServer_  at the same time, that's contradictorily. They may have a common base class, and a _MainServer_ may have a collection of _SubServers_, but a _SubServer_ never _**is a**_ _MainServer_. I'd recommend you to think that over again.

Comment: Thank you all , I will think again about the design :)